# The VBA function is not displaying the result in the specific cell where the conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of dates, and I want to display the sum result of the differences between start and end dates based on specific conditions. The conditions include the requirement for the start of January to be included, and the period between start and end dates to be greater than 30 days. However, when I execute the following formula in Excel, "=SumBasedOnCondition(C2:C93; D2:D93; E2:E93)", I only get a sum result from the first column to where the condition is met, and the rest of the values are not considered. For example, I may get results like 36, 36, No, NO...
Example of two rows from my data:

```
01/01/2023  17/01/2023  20
18/01/2023  31/01/2023  16
```

in this case i should get 36 in one of this celles because first of janary is included and period greater than 30 days

This is the VBA code that im trying

```
Function SumBasedOnCondition(startDates As Range, endDates As Range, valuesToSum As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sumResult As Double
    
    sumResult = 0
    
    For i = 1 To startDates.Rows.Count
        If (Month(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1 And _
            Month(endDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1 And _
            Year(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 2023 And _
            Year(endDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 2023) Then
            ' Sum the values in the specified range for the corresponding row
            sumResult = sumResult + valuesToSum.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    If sumResult > 30 Then
        SumBasedOnCondition = sumResult
    Else
        SumBasedOnCondition = "No"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Put some sample data into your post and the results you expect from that sample

Comment: Note that your cells are always one row off. You start the loop at `i = 2`. For the range `C2:C93`, `startDates.Cells(i, 1)` will read cell `C3`.

Comment: When you post your sample data, post it as **text** which can be easily copy/pasted, and **not** as a screenshot. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Yes i just noticed that but but even when i change to i=1 still the same result

Answer (score 0):

I would probably parameterise the function a little more, to give you more control:

```
Function SumBasedOnCondition(startDates As Range, endDates As Range, valuesToSum As Range, _
             lower_limit As Long, month_filter As Integer, year_filter As Integer, _
             Optional skiprows As Long = 0) As Variant
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sumResult As Double
    
    sumResult = 0
    
    For i = 1 + skiprows To startDates.Rows.Count
        If (Month(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = month_filter And _
            Month(endDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = month_filter And _
            Year(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = year_filter And _
            Year(endDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = year_filter) Then
            ' Sum the values in the specified range for the corresponding row
            sumResult = sumResult + valuesToSum.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    If sumResult > lower_limit Then
        SumBasedOnCondition = sumResult
    Else
        SumBasedOnCondition = "No"
    End If
    
End Function
```

To use it you could:

```
=SumBasedOnCondition(C2:C93; D2:D93; E2:E93; 30; 1; 2023)
```

Where:

```
C2:C93 is your StartDate data
D2:D93 is your EndDate data
E2:E93 is your ValuesToSum data
30 is your lower limit
1 is your month filter
2023 is your year filter
0 is your skiprows value, (optional, so not shown) as you're starting 
on row 2 so don't want to skip any rows.
```

Alternatively, you could **include** the header in your ranges, but set `skiprows` to 1 to ignore it.

```
=SumBasedOnCondition(C1:C93; D1:D93; E1:E93; 30; 1; 2023; 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort but i still get the same result

Comment: I've tweaked the code slightly and included a screengrab of it getting 36 with your example data

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely help if you provide sample data and expected results. But if I understand you correctly, that you should sum the results provided that 01/ß1/2023 exists in the list, then you need this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sumResult As Double
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
sumResult = 0

For i = 1 To startDates.Rows.Count
    If (((Day(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1 And _
    Month(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1 And _
    Year(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 2023) Or found = True) And _
    Year(startDates.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 2023) Then
        found = True
    ' Sum the values in the specified range for the corresponding row
        sumResult = sumResult + valuesToSum.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next i
```

The problem with your code is that as soon as the start date goes past 31/1/2023 then your `If` is failing, because the current row value is not a January.  Incidentally, your code only checks that the month is January, not that it contains the 1st of January.

My code gets around the February problem, by setting a Boolean flag to True, if the Range has already included 01/01/2023.